# Problems using Keras Model Subclassing, input shape=<unknown>

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, subclassing, resnet

Currently I am learning subclassing with Keras. Thus far I have built my models using the functional API. For the paper I try to recreate at the moment subclassing would be really helpful though.

My model is:

```py
class ResidualBlockdown(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self): 
        super(ResidualBlockdown, self).__init__()
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv3D(128, 1, padding="same")

        self.conv2 = layers.Conv3D(128, 3, padding="same")

       
        self.conv3 = layers.Conv3D(256, 1, padding="same")

        
    def call(self, x, training=True):
        #out = self.bn(x)
        out=x
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = self.bn(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = layers.Add()([out, x])
        
        return out


#Then let's create a single hourglass to later stack them:


class HourglassSingle(layers.Layer): #inp and output of an hourglass should be 96,192,96=3*2^5, #6*2^5
    def __init__(self):
         super(HourglassSingle, self).__init__()
         self.pool=layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2), strides=(2, 2,2), padding='same')
         self.cup =layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2,2), data_format=None)#interpolation="nearest"
         self.res=ResidualBlockdown()
         

    def call(self, x, training=True):
        l1=self.res(x)
        i1=self.res(l1)

        d1=self.pool(l1)
        l2=self.res(d1)
        i2=self.res(l2)

        d2=self.pool(l2)
        l3=self.res(d2)
        i3=self.res(l3)

        d3=self.pool(l3)
        l4=self.res(d3)
        i4=self.res(l4)

        d4=self.pool(l4)
        l5=self.res(d4)
        l6=self.res(l5)

        fi4=self.cup(l6)
        plus4=layers.Add()([fi4, i4])
        plus4prime=self.res(plus4)

        fi3=self.cup(plus4prime)
        plus3=layers.Add()([fi3, i3])
        plus3prime=self.res(plus3)

        fi2=self.cup(plus3prime)
        plus2=layers.Add()([fi2, i2])
        plus2prime=self.res(plus2)

        fi1=self.cup(plus2prime)
        plus1=layers.Add()([fi1, i1])
        plus1prime=self.res(plus1)

        return plus1prime
     

class TestHourGlassSingle(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestHourGlassSingle, self).__init__()
        self.crop=tf.keras.layers.Cropping3D(cropping=(2, 4, 12))
        self.HG=HourglassSingle()
        self.conv1=layers.Conv3D(50, 1, padding="same")
        self.conv2=layers.Conv3D(1, 1, padding="same")

    def call(self, x,training=True):
        p1=self.crop(x) #96, 192, 96
        p2=self.HG(p1)
        p3=self.conv1(p2)
        p4=self.conv1(p3)
        return p4


model=TestHourGlassSingle()
```

I do fitting on it using:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5), loss=custom_loss_function, metrics=["mae", euclidian_distancexpred, euclidian_distancextrue]) #custom_loss_function

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.4,
                              patience=1500, min_lr=1e-20)



tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)


model.fit(train_ds,  epochs=20000, validation_data=test_ds,  verbose=2 ,callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard_callback])
```

The tranining as well as the testing dataset is of shape (100, 200, 120,1). After I crop it, it receives the shape (96,192,96). My loss functions and metrics have all worked with functionally programmed UNets and should be fine as well as all the dataset creation and augmentation.

When I run it, I get an error saying:

```
File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\models\Landmark3_34HG.py", line 565, in call  *
                    out = self.conv1(out)
                File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
                    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
                File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional\base_conv.py", line 408, in _get_input_channel
                    if input_shape.dims[channel_axis].value is None:

                TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable


            Call arguments received by layer "residual_blockdown" "                 f"(type ResidualBlockdown):
              • x=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
              • training=True
```

The full error log will be shown below if need be. I have searched mutliple forums for a solution and all did the subclassing in the same manner. Can anyone tell me why the shape is ok for the cropping layer but does not get passed to my custom part? Does anyone know where my mistake lies?

Full error log:

```
Epoch 1/20000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\models\Landmark3_34HG.py", line 813, in <module>
    model.fit(train_ds,  epochs=20000, validation_data=test_ds,  verbose=2 ,callbacks=[reduce_lr, tensorboard_callback]) #validation_data=test_ds
  File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filexk8zl7ue.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filewlmonkim.py", line 11, in tf__call
    p2 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).HG, (ag__.ld(p1),), None, fscope)
  File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemam9ops1.py", line 10, in tf__call
    l1 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).res, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
  File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filed_9dqc_p.py", line 12, in tf__call
    out = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(out),), None, fscope)
TypeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filewlmonkim.py", line 11, in tf__call
        p2 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).HG, (ag__.ld(p1),), None, fscope)
    File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemam9ops1.py", line 10, in tf__call
        l1 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).res, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
    File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filed_9dqc_p.py", line 12, in tf__call
        out = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(out),), None, fscope)

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "test_hour_glass_single" "                 f"(type TestHourGlassSingle).

    in user code:

        File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\models\Landmark3_34HG.py", line 637, in call  *
            p2=self.HG(p1)
        File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filemam9ops1.py", line 10, in tf__call
            l1 = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).res, (ag__.ld(x),), None, fscope)
        File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filed_9dqc_p.py", line 12, in tf__call
            out = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(out),), None, fscope)

        TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "hourglass_single" "                 f"(type HourglassSingle).

        in user code:

            File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\models\Landmark3_34HG.py", line 589, in call  *
                l1=self.res(x)
            File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
                raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
            File "C:\Users\lenna\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filed_9dqc_p.py", line 12, in tf__call
                out = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(out),), None, fscope)

            TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "residual_blockdown" "                 f"(type ResidualBlockdown).

            in user code:

                File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\models\Landmark3_34HG.py", line 565, in call  *
                    out = self.conv1(out)
                File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
                    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
                File "C:\Users\lenna\DeepLearning\ImReg\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional\base_conv.py", line 408, in _get_input_channel
                    if input_shape.dims[channel_axis].value is None:

                TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable


            Call arguments received by layer "residual_blockdown" "                 f"(type ResidualBlockdown):
              • x=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
              • training=True


        Call arguments received by layer "hourglass_single" "                 f"(type HourglassSingle):
          • x=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
          • training=True


    Call arguments received by layer "test_hour_glass_single" "                 f"(type TestHourGlassSingle):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
      • training=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try. although its similar structure you create multiple channels using resudial block so when you use multiple of them in a row their dimentions doesnt match, simple way is to remove and modify them. But this is with the assumption that your model can be modified and it is not set in stone:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

class ResidualBlockdown(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, channels): 
        super(ResidualBlockdown, self).__init__()
        self.relu = tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv3D(channels // 2, 1, padding="same", input_shape=(None, None, None, None))
        self.bn2 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv3D(channels // 2, 3, padding="same")
        self.bn3 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.conv3 = layers.Conv3D(channels, 1, padding="same")

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(ResidualBlockdown, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, training=True):
        out = self.bn1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn3(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = layers.Add()([out, x])
        
        return out
    
#Then let's create a single hourglass to later stack them:

class HourglassSingle(layers.Layer): #inp and output of an hourglass should be 96,192,96=3*2^5, #6*2^5
    def __init__(self, channels=256):
        super(HourglassSingle, self).__init__()
        self.pool=layers.MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), strides=(2, 2,2), padding='same')
        self.cup =layers.UpSampling3D(size=(2,2,2), data_format=None)#interpolation="nearest"
        self.res1=ResidualBlockdown(channels)
        self.res2=ResidualBlockdown(channels)
        self.res3=ResidualBlockdown(channels)
        self.res4=ResidualBlockdown(channels)
        self.res5=ResidualBlockdown(channels)
        self.res6=ResidualBlockdown(channels)

    def call(self, x, training=True):
        l1=self.res1(x)

        d1=self.pool(l1)
        l2=self.res2(d1)

        d2=self.pool(l2)
        l3=self.res3(d2)

        d3=self.pool(l3)
        l4=self.res4(d3)

        d4=self.pool(l4)
        l5=self.res5(d4)

        l6=self.res6(l5)

        fi4=self.cup(l6)
        plus4=layers.Add()([fi4, l4])
        plus4prime=self.res5(plus4)

        fi3=self.cup(plus4prime)
        plus3=layers.Add()([fi3, l3])
        plus3prime=self.res4(plus3)

        fi2=self.cup(plus3prime)
        plus2=layers.Add()([fi2, l2])
        plus2prime=self.res3(plus2)

        fi1=self.cup(plus2prime)
        plus1=layers.Add()([fi1, l1])
        plus1prime=self.res2(plus1)

        return plus1prime
     
class TestHourGlassSingle(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestHourGlassSingle, self).__init__()
        self.crop=tf.keras.layers.Cropping3D(cropping=(2, 4, 12))
        self.HG = HourglassSingle(channels=256)
        self.conv1=layers.Conv3D(128, 1, padding="same")
        self.conv2=layers.Conv3D(1, 1, padding="same")

    def call(self, x,training=True):
        p1=self.crop(x)
        p2=self.HG(p1)
        p3=self.conv1(p2)
        p4=self.conv2(p3)
        return p4
    
    
model=TestHourGlassSingle()
```